# Use of modules, singletons and classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, es6-class

I have a design question about when to use a class in Javascript, singleton of the class or just export the module functions;

Let's say we have a very simple file pub-sub feature, which I want to use across the whole application, with basically 3 items;

- function to publish an event
- function to subscribe to an event
- List of subscribers

Of course I want to have one single list of subscribers across the app which is used when using the publish function (all subscribers receive a message).

I could do this by creating a module which exports the publish and subscribe but not the subscribers

```
 // pubsub.js
 const subscribers = [];

 function publish(event, data){...} // publishes to all subscribers in the list
 function subscribe(event, callback){...} // Adds a callback to the subscribers
 export { 
  publish, 
  subscribe
 }

 // other files;
 import {publish, subscribe} from 'pubsub'
```

But as far I know I can achieve the same result by creating a class; creating an instance and export that instance instead of just the functions

```
// pubsub.js 
class EventService {
    constructor() {
        this.subscribers = []; 
    }

    publish(event, data){...} // publishes to all subscribers in the list
    subscribe(event, callback){...} // Adds a callback to the subscribers
}

export default eventService = new EventService();

// other files; 
import eventService from 'pubsub'
```

And in the last case I can also export the class itself (which makes more sense usually) and create an instance at app start and share it across the app (with DI).

The question is; What is the way to go when you want to have some functions shared across the code, which shares the same list of items, and you want to ensure there is only a singleton active. (As having multiple instances of the EventService will give incorrect results when publishing to another instance)

(I am aware there are pubsub libraries, it's just an example of a piece of code that should be shared across the code in a single instance).

Comment: There are other possibilities as well, too many to enumerate in a comment. I would say that you should keep it simple. If you plan to just export and use a single instance don't bother creating a class because you're making your API far too complicated. Also, once the class is exposed you can't prevent people from instantiating it or extending it and then instantiating the extended classes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I might be too much influenced by how I usually do this things in C# / Java. I start out simple in this case.

Comment: You are doing the proper thing then, questioning the assumptions and intuitions you have in coming from these languages. In some cases you existing knowledge will apply well, for example C#'s `xs.Select(x => x + 1)` _**is**_ practically analogous to JavaScript's `xs.map(x => x + 1)`. In the case of classes, however, your knowledge of C# / Java will be of almost no help to you at all, for example Java's `value instanceof Type` _**is not**_  analogous to JavaScript's `value instanceof value`.